# What is the reverse operation of jQuery text()

Tags: jquery, html-escape-characters

I have a user input like

```
var input = "x + y > z"
```

I create an element like this:

```
var span = jQuery("<span/>").text(input)
```

How can I get the original text back, not escaped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.text()` will give you the text content. That will not be an escaped version. Whereas if you use `.html()` then the text would be escaped and returned.

```
var span = jQuery("<span/>").text(input)
var returnedText = span.text();
```